# How to find the MST of a Graph in |V| Time given a spanning tree plus another edge

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, undirected-graph, spanning-tree

I'm wondering how to go about solving this problem.

I'm given a graph `G = (V,E)`. This is a connected undirected weighted graph. 
The graph consists of a spanning tree and one additional edge. 

How would I come up with an algorithm that would compute the MST of the graph in `n = |V|` time complexity. 

I was thinking of Kruskal's Algorithm but it wouldn't meet the time complexity requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spanning tree plus one edge makes exactly one cycle.  Find the cycle using depth-first search, and then remove its heaviest edge.